# Couldn't load plugin GniPlannerFTTH

Tags: qgis, error, open-source-gis

I am using **FTTx Planner** (*Open Source element of Geospatial Network
Inventory system*) but when I try to use **GniPlannerFTTH** plugin in **QGIS** I get the following error:

> "Couldn't load plugin GniPlannerFTTH due to an error when calling its
>   classFactory() method"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be a bug report rather than a question on StackExchange.

Answer (score 1):

This message rely on Qgis couldn't find the classFactory method to use this plugin. As this plugin is not in the official repo you need to install it manually and take care of some points :

1. Be sure that your python interpreter have the **scipy** an **openpyxl** libs install. This is because the plugins rely on them. From the osgeo console (on Windows) or from a the bash console (in linux) execute `python` and try to import the libs : `import scipy` and `import openpyxl` if none of them return any errors they are installed. If not you need to install them with pip or easy_install. like so : `pip install scipy` and for the other one `pip install openpyxl`
2. Grab the 2 folders `GniPlannerFTTH`and `WorkContextTracer` and put them in the `*user_home_directory*/.qgis2/python/plugins/`
3. Then you should able to activate them without errors.