# QGIS, Python and GniPlannerFTTH Error

Tags: pyqgis

when trying to activate GniPlannerFTTH plugin on QGIS, I always get an error calles

> "Couldn't load plugin GniPlannerFTTH due to an error when calling its classFactory() method"

and further

> ImportError: No module named openpyxl

I successfully installed scipy and openpyxl and there were no errors that have been returned when importing them in python. I've done anything that @SIGIS wrote in [Couldn't load plugin GniPlannerFTTH](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/260471/couldnt-load-plugin-gniplannerftth).

In QGIS I also get the following traceback information and the Python path:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/PROGRA~2/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line
>   333, in startPlugin plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
>
> File
>   "C:/Users/user/.qgis2/python/plugins\GniPlannerFTTH__init__.py", line
>   31, in classFactory from gniplanner import GniPlannerFTTHPlugin
>
> File "C:/PROGRA~2/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line
>   607, in _import mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist,
>   level)
>
> File
>   "C:/Users/user/.qgis2/python/plugins\GniPlannerFTTH\gniplanner.py",
>   line 34, in from gniplanner_provider import GniPlannerFTTHProvider
>
> File "C:/PROGRA~2/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line
>   607, in _import mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist,
>   level)
>
> File
>   "C:/Users/user/.qgis2/python/plugins\GniPlannerFTTHgniplanner_provider.py",
>   line 32, in from planner_report import PlannerReport
>
> File "C:/PROGRA~2/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line
>   607, in _import mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist,
>   level)
>
> File
>   "C:/Users/user/.qgis2/python/plugins\GniPlannerFTTH\planner_report.py",
>   line 26, in from openpyxl import Workbook
>
> File "C:/PROGRA~2/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line
>   607, in _import mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist,
>   level)
>
> ImportError: No module named openpyxl

Python Path:

> C:/PROGRA~2/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing
>
> C:/PROGRA~2/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python
>
> C:/Users/user/.qgis2/python
>
> C:/Users/user/.qgis2/python/plugins
>
> C:/PROGRA~2/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
>
> C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\bin\python27.zip
>
> C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\DLLs
>
> C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib
>
> C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win
>
> C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk
>
> C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\bin
>
> C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27
>
> c:\progra~2\qgis2~1.18\apps\python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg
>
> c:\progra~2\qgis2~1.18\apps\python27\lib\site-packages\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win32.egg
>
> c:\progra~2\qgis2~1.18\apps\python27\lib\site-packages\shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win32.egg
>
> C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages
>
> C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32
>
> C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
>
> C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
>
> C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode
>
> C:/Users/user/.qgis2//python
>
> C:\Users\user.qgis2\python\plugins\mmqgis/forms
>
> C:/Users/user/Desktop/FttX Planner

Im struggling to interprete these information. Might there be a problem with the directory?

Answer (score 2):

The error log tells you that it can't find the openpyxl. You might install that lib for an other python interpreter, that's is declare in you path variable.

As I can see you had install Qgis in Windows And you took the standalone installer (because it went in the programme folder). Search in Qgis programme folder the osgeo shell icon. From there run `pip install openpyxl`. if it doesn't have `pip` 2 choices get the lib from [there](https://github.com/pypa/get-pip) 
or get the osgeo installer which is more customizable (I don't know I can say that).